# Creating data templates in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datatemplate, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of products in my $scope. My products look like the following:

```
function myController($scope) {
  $scope.products = [
    { id:1, name:"hamburger", image:"/img/hamburger.png" },
    { id:2, name:"fries", image:"/img/fries.png" },
    { id:3, name:"hot dog", image:"/img/hotDog.png" }
    ...
  ];
}
```

I have a file called food.html. That file looks like this:

```
<div>
  <div>{{name}}</div>
  <div><img ng-src="{{image}}" /></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to show a list of all of my products rendered with food.html in index.html via repeater. How do I do that? Currently, I have something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <div>Total Food Items: {{products.length}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat="product in products">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm stuck how to render each product using food.html. How do I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use food.html as an template then create directive for it.

```
angular.module('MyApp').directive('foodDetail', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div> <div>{{product.name}}</div> <div><img ng-src="{{product.image}}" /></div></div>',

    }
});
```

And index.html should be

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div>Total Food Items: {{products.length}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <div food-detail></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, I can't seem to get the template you entered to render. Is it missing something?

Comment: I have created plunkr here: [link]http://plnkr.co/edit/Z5SBYn1jKBeLVXXgnm5i?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

index.html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <!-- ... some code ... -->
    <div data-ng-view></div>
    <!-- ... some more code ... -->
</div>
```

Food.html:

```
<div>Total Food Items: {{products.length}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <div>{{name}}</div>
    <div><img ng-src="{{image}}" /></div>
</div>
```

Then, configure your routes with something like this in app.js:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/food', {
        templateUrl: 'food.html',
        controller: 'myController'
    })
});
```

Here is a resource with more information: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07